# PROTÉGÉ SPARQL QUERY TAB: cannot query for ontology-specific classes

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, protege

I am using SPARQL Query tab in Protege 5 to query an OWL ontology I have been constructing. I succeded in many kinds of queries, but when I use some specific class of my ontology inside the very same queries (that are apparently well formed) they return no results. Following, two of the problematic queries - assuming "Event" as one of the concepts of the ontology (http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2014/5/MyOnto#Event):

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX onto: <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2014/5/MyOnto#>

SELECT ?a  WHERE { ?a rdfs:subClassOf onto:Event }
```

and, with the same prefixes

```
SELECT ?a  WHERE { ?a rdfs:range onto:Event }
```

Both return no results. However, if I substitute "onto:Event" for, let's say, ?b, both return a long list of results - inclunding Event as a match for ?b.

Is it something I'm misusing or forgetting (although I've seen this pattern in several links on internet with people claiming to have got results) or is it a limitation of SPARQL or some issue of the Protege tab?

Comment: Do you *have* any properties which have onto:Event as the range?c  Without seeing your data, it's hard to say one way or another…

Comment: @meagar : Thanks for the reply. Sure a I have. The point is that if I substitute onto:Event by a variable, let's say ?b, I got triples refering to onto:Event, such as onto:precede rdfs:range onto:Event (though in the table of results they appear simplified, just as "precede" and "Event"). The same happens with "?a rdfs:subClassOf onto:Event" and with any other query in which I refer to a class of my ontology. It seems that I am misrepresenting them using this pattern onto:ClassName, but it is widely refered to be the correct way to do so. Can you figure out a possible reason?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor : Thanks for the reply! (in fact, the previous comment should be adressed to you) Yes, if I had provided some data, the answer might have been obvious. Thanks anyway.

Comment: So the answer to "Do you have any properties which have onto:Event (`http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2014/5/MyOnto#Event`) as the range?" is that you *didn't* have properties with onto:Event as the range. This is why it's important to show the data and the results.  It would have been pretty obvious in the results of your query that the URI wasn't the same as the prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, in fact, although the **URI** of the ontology is:

```
<http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2014/5/MyOnto#>
```

in the OWL document, the prefix used before class names is the **IRI**:

```
<http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-662#>
```

Thus, replacing the old `onto:` by

```
PREFIX onto: <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-662#>
```

solves the issue.

(Thanks to @Csongor from Protégé Project mail list, who found the answer.)

P.S.: It's also worthy to note that it can't be taken for granted that all the terms in the ontology will be `<current_ontology_URI#term>` - e.g. if one includes some terms in the ontology and then changes ontology URI, these terms will be identified as `<previous_ontology_URI#term>` and the new ones as `<current_ontology_URI#term>` (which was exactly the cause of the problem above).

Comment: The question should be closed because it was just a typographical error, but in any case, you should probably [accept your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, whenever using an ontology specific class there were no results although there should have been. My ontology (pizza.owl) was loaded from a local file.
I found that it is required to add the file name in the PREFIX.

```
PREFIX : <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>
```

After that I got the information that I expected.